# de Rham Cohomology of the complex projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I want to compute the de Rham cohomology of the complex projective spaces $P^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. I know what the result is, and I've seen many posts in the forum asking the same thing. The problem is that, in the course I attended, we didn't deal with $CW$-complexes and I don't know what a cell decomposition is. The main tool I can use is the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Can you give me some tips or some references? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Do you have the tools to prove that $P^n_\mathbb{C}=A\cup B$ such that $A\simeq P^{n-1}_\mathbb{C}$ and $B\simeq\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: If you prove the above then you can find the cohomologies of $P^1$ using Mayer-Vietoris. The by induction and MV you can find cohomologies of $P^n$.

Comment: No, I can't. And since I don't who are $A$ and $B$, I don't know neither who $A\cap B$ is...

Comment: Okay, i've done :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @hamedp I'm sorry to bother you again, but there is something which is not clear to me. To apply Mayer-Vietoris sequence to $P^n_{\mathbb{C}}$, I consider the two open sets: $U=\{[z_0:\dots:z_{n-1}:1]\in P^n_{\mathbb{C}}\}$ and $V=\{[z_0:\dots:z_{n-1}:0]\in P^n_{\mathbb{C}}\}$. (I'm using homogenous coordinates as equivalence classes). I want to formalize the fact that $U\cong \mathbb{C^n}$, $V\cong P^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $U\cap V\cong \mathbb{C}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: First of all V is closed not open. MV needs the interior of U and V to cover everything. With these sets you do not have that. Secondly $U\cap V$ is empty in you construction. Take an open covering with open sets similar to U.

Comment: Take $V=\{[0:\dots:0:1]\}^c$

Comment: $\{[0:\cdots:0:1]\}^c\neq \{[z_0:\cdots:z_{n-1}:0]\}$! $[0:\cdots:0:1]$ is a point, so for example $[0:\cdots:1:1]\in \{[0:\cdots:0:1]\}^c$ but $[0:\cdots:1:1]\notin \{[z_0:\cdots:z_{n-1}:0]\}$. Your new $V$ is open though. But your previous $V$ is closed.

Comment: Remember the topology of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is the induced topology from $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ under the map $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^n$ which sends a line to a point.

Comment: @avati91 Did you manage to solve your problem? Would you be willing to share your solution?